# Conducting a t-test on differences?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, t-test

I'm interested in looking at how employment changes in a treatment and control group measured at the census block level after the start of an employment-related policy. There are 1,250 census blocks in my treatment group and 1,250 census blocks in my control group.

I have employment numbers for 2000 and 2010, and I'm interested in seeing how employment changed from 2000 to 2010 in the average census block in the treatment group compared to the control group.

Here's an example of what my data looks like:

[image]

Is it valid to conduct a t-test of the employment difference column (2010 employment - 2000 employment) so that I could see whether mean employment difference in the treatment group is statistically different than the mean employment difference in the control group?

Specifically, the code that I would run looks like this:

`t.test(employment_different ~ treatment_flag, data = df)`

Comment: Your body text seems to be asking about a signed difference, not an absolute difference (per your title); can you clarify this seeming discrepancy? It occurs to me that you might be using "absolute" to suggest an ordinary difference rather than a relative difference, but in that case the term in the title is likely to confuse readers who might be looking for a question about a t-test on the absolute values of some difference.$A_i=|Y_i-X_i|$ say.

Comment: Or you could use a linear model on the original data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is valid. This is known as the difference-in-differences method. It's also equivalent to a mixed 2x2 ANOVA with time as a within-subjects factor and treatment as a between-subjects factor. The p-value for the t-test will equal the p-value for the time-by-treatment interaction (which is the effect you want to estimate).

Comment: Thanks. Does it matter if the employment sizes in the two groups are different to begin with? For example, say there are 10,000 people in all of the treatment census blocks but only 5,000 people in all of the control census blocks in 2000.

Comment: No, as long as you have both time points for all blocks.